# Serializing collections only one level deep with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization

I'm running into an issue while attempting to return recursive serialized objects generated by Entity Framework 6 through a Web API.  Here's a small example of my problem:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public partial class Thing
{
    public Thing()
    {
        this.OtherThings = new HashSet<OtherThings>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int ThingId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ThingName { get; set; }

    //Not included in serialization
    public virtual ICollection<OtherThing> OtherThings { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public partial class OtherThing
{
    public OtherThing()
    {
        this.Things = new HashSet<Things>();
    }
    //I want these
    [DataMember]
    public int OtherThingId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string OtherThingName { get; set; }

    //Do NOT want this from GetAllThings() to avoid circular references
    public virtual ICollection<Things> Things { get; set; }
}
```

The decorators are generated from the Context.tt file, and there are a *lot* more properties in my real object, making hand-editing each of these impossible - not to mention the files are auto-generated.

I retrieve the collection of `Things` from my database with this simple method:

```
public static class Repo {
    internal static IQueryable<Thing> GetAllThings()
    {
        //Context is an initialized database context
        return Context.Things;
    }
}
```

Which returns the entire collection of `Things`, which contain `OtherThings`, which each contain more `Things`.  The problem becomes obvious when I try to serialize this as a Web API response:

```
public class API {
    //This response is serialized to JSON
    public List<Thing> GetAllThings()
    {
        var things = Repo.GetAllThings();
        //Do something here to exclude 
        return things.ToList();
    }
}
```

Naturally, the serializer will fail (or overflow), because there are circular references.  Normally I would add `[DataIgnore]` to the offending properties and just forget about DataContracts altogether, but if I request a collection of `Things`, I just want each connected `OtherThing`, and vice-versa.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that Context.Things is of type DbSet you can use

```
return Context.Things.Select(s => s).Include(s => s.OtherThings);
```

Comment: Hmm, I gave that a shot, but it seems the serializer is very persistant, and doesn't care what is `Include`-d with a query.  The EF6 template also generates HashSets, which I edited my question to include.  Thank you though!